# Broken Migrations in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I created and subsequently changed a DecimalField in my models.  Now, when I try to run `python manage.py migrate` I get the following error:

```
decimal.InvalidOperation: quantize result has too many digits for current context
```

After reading the various related questions here on SO I have tried increasing the max_digits, which doesn't help.  **I have manually deleted the model in my postgreSQL database** expecting to be able to recreate it when I migrate the models but I still get this same error and am not able to migrate the models and recreate the model in the database.

This is the model in question:

```
class Version(models.Model):
    version_number = models.DecimalField(default=1.0, max_digits=3,
                                     decimal_places=2)
```

What can I do to remedy this?

**EDIT**  When I changed the DecimalField I changed the `max_digits`

Comment: can you mention what were the changes you made in your DecimalField?

Comment: try increasing max_digits more, say 10

Comment: yeah, I did that already, no dice.  My main problem now is that the Version model doesn't exist in the database anymore because I deleted it.  I'm not able to recreate it as I'm unable to run the `manage.py migrate` command because of this error.

Comment: Did you use migrate to delete the model?

Comment: No, i deleted it using `psql` on my db machine.

Comment: I've tried deleting the last few migration files and running `migrate` again, I don't get the error but while Django says it has created the new Version model it's not created in the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems your problem isn't actually with DecimalField, but with the manual deletion of your table as a troubleshooting step.

As far as I know, the `makemigrations` tool doesn't make changes according to what is in the existing database, but rather what has been defined in prior migrations.

So if you change something without using it, you'll have to manually create or edit the migration file to correct it.

See the following for examples of editing migration files:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/writing-migrations/

I'm not sure what the protocol is here, but it might be possible to locate the migration where the table was first created and copypaste the applicable sequence into your pending migration file.

Comment: I'm developing in Vagrant and I ended up destroying my database machine, bringing it up again and running the migrations again.  I had to re-enter all my data, but it wasn't much, and everything is working fine now.  Thankyou Adam, even though I took a bit of a 'burn & rebuild' problem solving approach, this was really useful.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds kind of what I ended up doing in my own case. Sometimes it's just easier to start over after you've borked the migrations.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so you have problem with setting the default value here:

You need to import Decimal.

```
from decimal import Decimal
class Version(models.Model):
    version_number = models.DecimalField(default=Decimal('1.00'), max_digits=3,
                                     decimal_places=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

So i had the same issue, no matter how i changed the existing DecimalField, i kept getting this error (decimal.InvalidOperation)

To look it up, i set a pdb/set_trace in django utils.py (...\site-packages\django\db\backends) to see what is causing this exception

On my example it was using max_digits=4 and decimal_places=4 (which again, wasn't the most recent values for this model's field).
So i went up in the functions, and found out that one of the early migrations was causing this.

I changed the migration and all other migrations that related to this model's field to be the recent version and it was fixed